# Declaring custom woocommerce product type as virtual / downloadable only

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to set up a woocommerce custom product type so that its as minimal as possible - no options I don't specifically designate.

Still, despite the declaration below, the custom product meta box still shows "shipping" shipping options.

How do I get rid of the shipping options? And on that note, any other that I may wish to remove.

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'ss_create_custom_product_type');

function ss_create_custom_product_type() {

    // declare the product class
    class WC_Product_Wdm extends WC_Product {    
        public function __construct($product) {
            $this->product_type = 'ss_stock_image';


            $this->virtual = 'yes';
            $this->downloadable = 'yes';
            $this->manage_stock = 'no';   

            parent::__construct($product);
            // add additional functions here            
        }     
    }        
}
```

[image]

UPDATE:

I've updated the class per suggestion. Yet I wonder why the code is not getting fired.

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'ss_create_custom_product_type');

function ss_create_custom_product_type() {

    // declare the product class
    class WC_Product_Wdm extends WC_Product {

        public function __construct($product) {
            $this->product_type = 'ss_stock_image';

            add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', array($this, 'remove_tabs'), 10, 1);

            parent::__construct($product);
        }

        public function remove_tabs($tabs) {

            /**
             * The available tab array keys are:
             * 
             * general
             * inventory
             * shipping
             * linked_product
             * attribute
             * variations
             * advanced
             */
            unset($tabs['shipping']);
            return $tabs;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you positively sure that overriding those class properties then corresponds to the actual tabs being hidden in the UI and have you isolated the code that is responsible for printing those tabs in the UI in order to confirm?

Comment: Good question. After looking at the js files, I concluded that the tabs must be assigned based on the class's setup. But I could be wrong. JS files did not show anything obvious other than generic hide/show functions that apply systematically to custom product types.

Comment: This question requires knowledge about third party plugin, so [it is off-topic here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @1Up You are not instantiating your `WC_Product_Wdm` class, for example, you need to add: `new WC_Product_Wdm()` after your class declaration in order for your class constructor to be called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking further into the WooCommerce source, they fortunately, provide a filter named `woocommerce_product_data_tabs` which will allow you to conditional unset tabs.

I've provided an example below:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', function($tabs) {

    /**
     * The available tab array keys are:
     * 
     * general
     * inventory
     * shipping
     * linked_product
     * attribute
     * variations
     * advanced
     */

    unset($tabs['shipping']);
    return $tabs;

}, 10, 1);
```

You may also filter the product type drop down menu using the `product_type_selector` filter and also the product type options checkboxes using the `product_type_options` filter.

Example:

```
add_filter('product_type_selector', function($product_type) {

    /**
     * The available product type selection array keys are:
     * 
     * simple
     * grouped
     * external
     * variable
     */

    unset($product_type['variable']); //as an example...
    return $product_type;

}, 10, 1);
```

Example:

```
add_filter('product_type_options', function($product_options) {

    /**
     * The available product type options array keys are:
     * 
     * virtual
     * downloadable
     */

    unset($product_options['downloadable']); //as an example...
    return $product_options;

}, 10, 1);
```

For your reference I found these filters by first looking at the `add_meta_boxes` method contained within the `WC_Admin_Meta_Boxes` class within `includes/admin/class-wc-admin-meta-boxes.php`;

From there you will note that they add a meta box, whose id is, `woocommerce-product-data` and the callback of which is `WC_Meta_Box_Product_Data::output` found within `includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php`.

It is within this `output` method that the filters `woocommerce_product_data_tabs`,  `product_type_selector` and `product_type_options` exist.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. It works outside as a function, but I can't get it working within the class custom product class itself. But this is sufficient to at least get me started, so thank you very much.

Comment: @1Up In your example code, you have a class which extends `WC_Product` wrapped in a function in which is called on the back of the `plugins_loaded` hook, but are you actually instantiating, anywhere, your `WC_Product_Wdm` class? Because if you are not, then code within that class is never getting called.

Comment: I've updated the question. This should work no? After all, if it is creating the custom product type, it should zip right through the add_filter function as well, no? Why is this backfiring? Your right - I placed a die() in the function just to see if it was being called and it is not.

Comment: I found a nice work-around. See below answer. Too hackish? Is there a more elegant solution? In any case, seems sufficient -- thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually @userabuser has the more complete answer, but to overcome this problem I was able to simply add a "hide" class this way:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', function($tabs) {

    array_push($tabs['shipping']['class'], 'hide_if_ss_stock_image');
    return $tabs;

}, 10, 1);
```

Notice the `hide_if_ss_stock_image` class that is added.